# Could we get some feedback on what needs to improve in this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42916/print-the-twelve-days-of-christmas-with-twelve-different-coding-languages) has a few downvotes but no explanation yet. Although it's beyond me to answer it, I like that it exists and I'm looking forward to seeing answers to it. Could we discuss what about it is attracting downvotes and what needs to improve?

Should it be put on hold in the meantime to prevent answers until it is fine tuned?

Comment: I would support it. I would, even more, support putting it on hold and copying it over to the sandbox. I will also warn that there are questions very similar to it, such as the numerous 99 bottles of beer questions scattered throughout the Internet.

Comment: @impinball the question has been edited since I wrote this meta post, but it still seems contradictory so I've voted to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Eh... Good point. I didn't really look at when it was created.

Answer (score -3):

Looks fine to me. His current explanation seems clear:

```
The program is started
The program prints the appropriate verse
The program writes the source code for the next program to file, which in turn contains the code for the rest, and so on.
The program compiles (if needed) the next program, and runs it.
```

Comment: This contradicts the second paragraph though.